# Yii2 array elements to display in different rows in detail view

Tags: arrays, yii2, yii2-basic-app, detailview

In my project I have a function which returns an array of elements. these array of elements have converted into string using implode and has been called in the detail view. Here my detail view displays all the elements in 1 single row.
I want each and every array element to be displayed in different rowsof detail view.

**My function which returns array elements.**

```
  public function getHazStatement(){
        $codes = array();
        $pLines = GhsHazStatements::find()->where(['haz_id' => $this->getHazID()])->all();
        foreach ($pLines as $pLine){
            $codes[] = $pLine->haz_statement;
            //var_dump($codes); exit();
        }
     //  var_dump(); exit();
        return implode(', ', $codes);
    }

    public function getHazCode(){
        $codes = array();
        $pLines = GhsHazStatements::find()->where(['haz_id' => $this->getHazID()])->all();
        foreach ($pLines as $pLine){
            $codes[] = $pLine->haz_code;
            //var_dump($codes); exit();
        }
     //  var_dump(); exit();
        return implode(', ', $codes);
    }
```

My view file detail view.

```
 [
                           'label' => $model->getHazCode(),
                           'value' => $model->getHazStatement(),
                           'options' => ['class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered detail-view','style'=> 'width:500px'], 
               ],
```

My output is :

[image: click here]

In my output you can see that there are two elements in the same row.. I want them to be in two different rows in detail view. How can I achieve this? Any possible solution?

Thank you

Comment: What is the problem exactly? You don't know how to prepare rows array? Or how to pass rows array into a view? Or how to render array as table rows inside a view?

Comment: I'd recommend you to declare `hasMany` relation to `GhsHazStatements` inside your class, use this relation to get `GhsHazStatements[]` and pass this array into a view. It is quite simple. And why do you need to pass css class names (and even style!) into a view? It looks like a bad practice

Comment: I have declared hasMany relation already.. I have the same function which will display multiple array elements at single time. And I need to split each array element in single row and display.. .This is my problem.

Comment: So... this result (on image) is fit on your needs and you just want to show modal window with splitted row elements when user clicks on a row?  Or detail view is another page?

Answer (score 0):

In your class:

```
public YourClass extends ActiveRecord 
{
    ... 

    public function getHazStatemets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(GhsHazStatements::className(), ['haz_id' => '<haz id column name in your class>']);
    }
}
```

In your conroller:

```
$this->render('<your view file name>', [
    'haz_statements' => $yourClassInstance->getHazStatements()->all(),
    'options' => ... // try to avoid passing CSS classes to from view controller
])
```

In your view:

```
<?php foreach($haz_statement as $statement) ?>

<tr>
    <td>
        <?= $statement->haz_code ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?= $statement->haz_statement ?>
    </td>
</tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not exactly understood your question.

If you want to have two rows and info..: (for example)

```
[
   'label' => $model->getHazCode(),
   'value' => "detail",
   'options' => ['class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered detail-view','style'=> 'width:500px'], 
],
[
   'label' => $model->getHazStatement(),
   'value' => "detail",
   'options' => ['class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered detail-view','style'=> 'width:500px'], 
],
```

But if you want a list of ...

When you want a list of rows, this is the same GridView

Anyway, I hope the following code will help you.
Please disable Show Header (see below)

```
  $query = GhsHazStatements::find()->where(['haz_id' => $this->getHazID()]);
  $dataProvider = new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
     'query' => $query,
        ]);
  echo yii\grid\GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'haz_statement',
        'haz_code',
      ],
    'showHeader' => false,
  ]);
```